# How can I use a parameter from sharedPreferences in workmanager in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, notifications, sharedpreferences, workmanagers

I am trying to send a notification based on parameter saved the user saves on sharedPreferences and is added to the url to make the call. The notification is working if I write the savedCity but when I try to get from sharedPreferences it fails. How can I make this work?

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    String savedCity = "";

 //    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 //     savedCity = prefs.getString('defaultCity') ?? ""; 

    if (task == 'uniqueKey') {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$savedCity&units=metric&appid=$API_KEY'));
      Weather dataComingFromTheServer = Weather.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

      final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
          'your channel description',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          showWhen: false);
      const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
      NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0,
          dataComingFromTheServer.name,
          '${dataComingFromTheServer.weather[0].description} ${dataComingFromTheServer.main.tempMin}ºC - ${dataComingFromTheServer.main.tempMax}ºC',
          platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: 'item x');
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
  AndroidInitializationSettings(
      '@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
  IOSInitializationSettings();
  final MacOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsMacOS =
  MacOSInitializationSettings();
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      macOS: initializationSettingsMacOS);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

  Workmanager.initialize(
      callbackDispatcher,
      isInDebugMode:
      true);

  Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
    "1",
    "uniqueKey",
    frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

```
void setPreference(String cityName) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString('defaultCity', cityName);
```

}

Comment: How you are saving savedCity to shared preference,  that code should be here

Comment: I edited with the method I'm using to save the defaultCity in sharedPreferences. I'm using it in another screen and it is saving and retrieving alright but not on the workManager to get the notification with the city saved

Comment: @HenriqueTavolaro have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

I uses `await prefs.reload();`  each time before get, and it's work.